# How to create a exception handling and logging class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, delegates, n-tier-architecture

I am working on a small project, I am trying to create a layer that will handle exception and logging.

This layer will sit in between User interface and DAL, mostly like BAL  which will have some generic method that will then initiate further call to Data access layer.

Some thing like this

```
Public Class ExceptionHandler
{
//which should take a method name,parameters and return a object.
Public T InitiateDatabaseCall(//method name as input,parameters)
{
try
{
//then make the call to the method using the input parameter and pass the parameters
}
catch(Exception e)
{
// do logging
}
}
```

This layer will act as center repository to handle and log exception. I am not able to create the method that i described can experts provide some snippet that will show case this scenario.

Edited: With code added

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            BAL b = new BAL();
            var ll = b.GetFieldList("xxxxyyyy");

        }





    public class BAL
    {
        public List<Fields> GetFieldList(string screen)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(screen))
            {
                ExceptionHandler.InitiateCall(() =>GetList(screen) ));
            }
        }

    }


    public static class ExceptionHandler
    {
        public T InitiateCall<T>(Func<T>method,object[] parms) where T : object 
        {
            try
            {
                return method.Invoke();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }

    public class DAL
    {

        public  List<Fields> GetList(string name)
        {
            VipreDBDevEntities context = new VipreDBDevEntities();
            return context.Database.SqlQuery<Fields>("SCREEN_FIELDS_SELECT @SCREEN_NAME", name).ToList();
        }
    }
```

It gives error GetList() does not exist in current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these kind of things AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is a really good fit.

These are cross-cutting concerns that are cluttering code if not done properly.

See for an example AOP framework PostSharp. Even with the free version that is simple to code. There are also (might be paid) build-in aspects for that, like http://doc.postsharp.net/exception-tracing.

A simple alternative is using a Func or Action (try it out in a Console App):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExceptionHandler.InitiateDatabaseCall(() => CallDb("Dummy"));
    ExceptionHandler.InitiateDatabaseCall<int>(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); });
}

int CallDb(string justToShowExampleWithParameters)
{
    return 5;   
}

public static class ExceptionHandler
{
    public static T InitiateDatabaseCall<T>(Func<T> method)
    {
        try
        {
            return method.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // do logging
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return default(T); // or `throw` to pass the exception to the caller
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
based on your added code in the question you can solve the error about GetList() by some minor modifications:

```
static void Main(string[] args)    {
    BAL b = new BAL();
    var ll = b.GetFieldList("xxxxyyyy");
}

public class BAL
{
    public List<Fields> GetFieldList(string screen)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(screen))
        {
            return ExceptionHandler.InitiateCall(() => new DAL().GetList(screen)); // Slight modification of your code here
        }
        else
        {
            return null; // or whatever fits your needs
        }
    }
}

public class ExceptionHandler
{
    public static T InitiateCall<T>(Func<T> method) 
    {
        try
        {
            return method.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}

public class DAL
{
    public  List<Fields> GetList(string name)
    {
        VipreDBDevEntities context = new VipreDBDevEntities();
        return context.Database.SqlQuery<Fields>("SCREEN_FIELDS_SELECT @SCREEN_NAME", name).ToList();
    }
}
```

You don't need the `object[] parms` parameter in `InitiateCall` given the provided code. Any paramaters you need for the method call are given in the `Func<T>`

Comment: that is pretty close to what i was thinking, I have edited my question with the latest, there is a error however about the method.... have a look

Comment: GetList() is defined in another class, so `ExceptionHandler.InitiateCall(() =>GetList(screen) ));
` needs to be changed to `return ExceptionHandler.InitiateCall(() => new DAL().GetList(screen));`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think loging should be done in two ways:

1. Step logging (when you log some step in your code)
2. Scope logging (when you log begin/end of some code or it's time)

So, I always choose to create ILogger class with these two ways:

```
   public sealed class Logger : ILogger
    {
        private readonly Serilog.ILogger _seriLogger;

        public Logger(Serilog.ILogger seriLogger)
        {
            _seriLogger = seriLogger;
        }

        public void Debug(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            _seriLogger.Debug(format, args);
        }

        public void Info(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            _seriLogger.Information(format, args);
        }

        public void Warn(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            _seriLogger.Warning(format, args);
        }

        public void Error(Exception e, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            _seriLogger.Error(e, format, args);
        }

        public void Fatal(Exception e, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            _seriLogger.Fatal(e, format, args);
        }

        public IDisposable GetScope(string name, long timeout = 0)
        {
            return new LoggerScope(this, name, timeout);
        }
    }

    internal class LoggerScope : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        private readonly string _name;

        private readonly long _timeout;

        private readonly Stopwatch _sw;

        private bool ExceedScope
        {
            get { return _timeout > 0; }
        }

        public LoggerScope(ILogger logger, string name, long timeout)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _name = name;
            _timeout = timeout;

            if (!ExceedScope)
            {
                _logger.Debug("Start execution of {0}.", name);
            }
            _sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _sw.Stop();

            if (ExceedScope)
            {
                if (_sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= (long)_timeout)
                {
                    _logger.Debug("Exceeded execution of {0}. Expected: {1}ms; Actual: {2}ms.", _name, _timeout.ToString("N"), _sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("N"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.Debug("Finish execution of {0}. Elapsed: {1}ms", _name, _sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("N"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, If I want to log something, I use it like this, without AOP:

```
using(_log.GetScope("Some describable name"))
{
   //Some code here
}
```

Comment: This does not address the exception handling. I think the question is to create some kind of method wrapper to write exception handling, and logging of the exception, once and use it for many methods.